# Javascript map over array of obj with another array to get different key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I am not sure why I having such a difficult time with this, but I have an array of ids that I am trying to use to map over an array of objects to find the corresponding id but return the value from a different key.

i.e.: 
`arr=[13, 1, 16]`

```
arrObj= [{
          id: 1,
          name: "cat"
         }, {
          id: 10,
          name: "tiger", 
         }, {
          id: 3,
          name: "dog", 
         }, {
          id: 16,
          name: "bear", 
         }, {
          id: 8,
          name: "fish", 
         }, {
          id: 13,
          name: "goat", 
         }]
```

and I want it to return:
`["goat", "cat", "bear"]`

I have a nested map function that does this but returns undefined for the objects that do not have a corresponding ID. I could filter out the undefineds from the returned array, but it seems that there is a cleaner/more efficient way to do this.

What is the cleanest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and search with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for the corresponding object. Then take `name` as return value.

```js
var arr = [13, 1, 16],
    arrObj = [{ id: 1, name: "cat" }, { id: 10, name: "tiger" }, { id: 3, name: "dog" }, { id: 16, name: "bear" }, { id: 8, name: "fish" }, { id: 13, name: "goat" }],
    result = arr.map(id => arrObj.find(o => o.id === id).name);

console.log(result);
```

For a lots of data, you could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and build it by mapping key value pairs and then map the result of the map.

```js
var arr = [13, 1, 16],
    arrObj = [{ id: 1, name: "cat" }, { id: 10, name: "tiger" }, { id: 3, name: "dog" }, { id: 16, name: "bear" }, { id: 8, name: "fish" }, { id: 13, name: "goat" }],
    result = arr.map(
        Map.prototype.get,
        new Map(arrObj.map(({ id, name }) => [id, name]))
    );

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You may not want to nest loops if you can help it, and you can definitely help it in this case. By transforming the array of objects once gives you an object that can be used to lookup values. So there is no need to run 'find' every iteration, it is just not performant at all. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50994305/5595673

Comment: @MohammedSiddeeq, you are right, an object would work too. for the second approach i included a map, which should be faster than continuing using `find`.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```js
var arr=[13, 1, 16];
var arrObj= [{
          id: 1,
          name: "cat"
         }, {
          id: 10,
          name: "tiger", 
         }, {
          id: 3,
          name: "dog", 
         }, {
          id: 16,
          name: "bear", 
         }, {
          id: 8,
          name: "fish", 
         }, {
          id: 13,
          name: "goat", 
         }];

var result = arr.map(id => arrObj.find(x => x.id == id)).map(x => x.name)
console.log(result);
// ["goat", "cat", "bear"]
```

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (from MDN web docs):

> method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided
>   function on every element in the calling array.

[`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (from MDN web docs):

> method returns the **value** of the **first element** in the array that
>   satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) is
>   returned.

Comment: Note that the loop is double, but i separate the filter and map to be more clear, you can do it in the first  loop

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to not nest any loops:

1. reduce your array of objects to a map of 'id-values' **idValueMap**
2. map through your array of 'ids' **idArr** using the **idValueMap** to get
   the corresponding values for each id in constant time.

**Thought Process**

Understand that the biggest problem is the data itself. Don't let insufficient  data types or structures force you you have a bad solution/code. Transform the data such to what you need so that you can create a proper solution.

Basically imagine if the **objArr** was just a Map that you could use to look up the values for an id.... then the solution is straight forward. So let's make that happen and then the rest falls into place. Data Data Data is what I always say :)

*Rule of thumb NEVER run a loop inside of a loop if you can help it. FYI: filter, find, map, indexOf .... are all loops internally, do not nest them unless you absolutely must.*

This solution is by far the most performant. This way you are not running **O(n^2)** (very BAD), you are instead running **O(n)** (very GOOD):

```js
    const idArr = [ 13, 1, 16 ];
    const objArr= [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "cat"
      }, 
      {
        id: 10,
        name: "tiger", 
      }, 
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "dog", 
      }, 
      {
        id: 16,
        name: "bear", 
      }, 
      {
        id: 8,
        name: "fish", 
      }, 
      {
        id: 13,
        name: "goat", 
      }
    ];
    
    const idValueMap = objArr.reduce((acc, { id, name }) => ({ ...acc, [id]: name }), {});
    let output = idArr.map((id) => idValueMap[id]);
    console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

There have been a lot of good answers already, however i feel the need to push for newer syntax as it is greater to work with in the long run.

```
const getNamesBasedOnIds = (arr, listOfIds) => {
   return arr.reduce(((sum, element) => 
      [...sum, ...(listOfIds.includes(element.id) ? [element.name] : [])]),
   []);
}

const animals = getNamesBasedOnIds(arrObj, [13,1,16]);
```

Using `Array.filter`, then `Array.map` requires you to run through the `Array` max twice.

With `Array.reduce` you can add `elements` to the `sum` if they exists in `listOfIds`, then after running through the `arrObj` once you have the result

`[...sum, ...(listOfIds.includes(element.id) ? [element.name] : [])]` is pretty slow, but its more for showing the use of spear operators

The above is equivalent to

`sum.concat(listOfIds.includes(element.id) ? element.name : [])]`

The fastest way, is to use `Array.push`

```
if(listOfIds.includes(element.id)){
   sum.push(element.name);
}
return sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first use [**`.filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter and then use [**`.map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to output the desired properties

here

```js
var arr = [13, 1, 16],
    arrObj = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "cat"
    }, {
        id: 10,
        name: "tiger",
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "dog",
    }, {
        id: 16,
        name: "bear",
    }, {
        id: 8,
        name: "fish",
    }, {
        id: 13,
        name: "goat",
    }];

var res = arrObj.filter(o => arr.indexOf(o.id) >= 0);

console.log(res.map(o => o['name']))
```